# How to include node_modules in a separate browserify vendor bundle

Tags: node.js, angularjs, browserify

I am trying to convert an AngularJS app to use browserify. I have installed all my bower packages in node_modules using napa. Now I want to browserify them into a separate vendor bundle and declare them as 'external' dependencies. I would like to give them aliases, so that I can "require('angular')" instead of "require('angular/angular')", as it seems you can do with externals.

The examples I have seen (e.g. http://benclinkinbeard.com/posts/external-bundles-for-faster-browserify-builds/) all assume that I have downloaed the vendor files into a 'lib' directory. I want to just bundle my vendor files from node_modules. It seems like it should be easy but I can't see how to do it.

Answer (score 42):

I was just trying to do the same thing. I think you need to use `--require` for the vendor bundle and `--export` for the application's so that the dependencies don't get bundled twice.

This worked for me using browserify's api and gulp (lodash and pixijs being my node_modules):

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var handleErrors = require('../util/handleErrors');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');


gulp.task('libs', function () {
  return browserify()
    .require('lodash')
    .require('pixi.js')
    .bundle()
    .on('error', handleErrors)
    .pipe(source('libs.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
  return browserify('./src/main.js')
    .external('lodash')
    .external('pixi.js')
    .bundle()
    .on('error', handleErrors)
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('src/**', ['scripts']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['libs', 'scripts', 'watch']);
```

Of course, this solution is a pain to maintain...  So I patched browserify to accept arrays in `require` and `external` and then you can do this which I think it's a lot better:

```js
var gulp         = require('gulp');
var browserify   = require('browserify');
var handleErrors = require('../util/handleErrors');
var source       = require('vinyl-source-stream');

var packageJson = require('../../package.json');
var dependencies = Object.keys(packageJson && packageJson.dependencies || {});


gulp.task('libs', function () {
  return browserify()
    .require(dependencies)
    .bundle()
    .on('error', handleErrors)
    .pipe(source('libs.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
  return browserify('./src/main.js')
    .external(dependencies)
    .bundle()
    .on('error', handleErrors)
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('package.json', ['libs']);
  gulp.watch('src/**', ['scripts']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['libs', 'scripts', 'watch']);
```

That's the best I could come up with...  Please, let me know if you find a better way.

Comment: Thanks for the response Oscar. I put my Browserify adventure on hold for now, so unfortunately cannot verify this answer. When I revisit the problem I will try to remember to test and accept your answer.

Comment: `So I patched browserify`  any chance you could send that in as a pull request?

Comment: hi there, this patch was already merged [here](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/pull/742).

Comment: Is it possible to just get the frontend dependencies instead of getting all of the dependencies in package.json (which will include gulp itself)? I don't want to bundle gulp itself in the browserify bundle.

Comment: @apple16 that's what `devDependencies` are for

Answer (score 0):

I also face this issue. Because it was huge file when all vendor library in same file. So browser always stuck with downloading more than 10MB file. File minification also was not solution because it was take more time to compile and that was not helpful for development.

I have kept `vendor.js` and `app.js` for separate node modules and application scripts. It's like this.

Sample vendor.js (src/app/vendor.js)

```
/**
 * Node modules
 */
require('angular');
require('angular-cookies');
require('angular-ui-router');
require('angular-aria');
require('angular-animate');
....
```

Sample app.js (src/app/app.js)

```
/**
 * App Common Modules
 */
require('./modules/about/about.routing.js');
require('./modules/home/home.routing.js');

/**
 * Services
 */
require('./shared/services/order.js');
require('./shared/services/product.js');


/**
 * Directives
 */
require('./shared/directives/dropzone.js');
require('./shared/directives/tab-change.js');


angular
    .module('myApp', [
        //------------- Node modules ------------//
        'ui.router',
        'ngMaterial',


        //------------- App Common modules ------------//

        //About
        'cloudDecor.routing.about',
        'cloudDecor.controller.about',


        //Home
        'cloudDecor.routing.home',
        'cloudDecor.controller.home',


        //------------- Services --------------//

        'cloudDecor.service.order',


        //------------- Directives ------------//
        'cloudDecor.directive.dropzone',
        'cloudDecor.directive.tab-change'

    ]);
```

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),   
    browserify = require('browserify'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');


//App js
gulp.task('app_js', function() {
    // Grabs the app.js file
    browserify({
            entries: ['./src/app/app.js'],
            debug: true
        })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('main.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});

//Vendor js
gulp.task('vendor_js', function() {
    // Grabs the app.js file
    browserify({
        entries: ['./src/app/vendor.js']
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('vendor.min.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(uglify({ mangle: false }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['app_js', 'vendor_js']);
```

Make sure include `vendor.js` before use `main.js` in `index.html`

```
<html>
<body>

<!--Vendor js, See src/vendor.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.min.js"></script>

<!--App scripts, See src/app.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This [solution](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/using-gulpjs-instead-of-webpack-to-split-vendor-and-app-scripts) looks great:

```
var packageJSON = require('./package.json');
var dependencies = Object.keys(packageJSON && packageJSON.dependencies || {});

gulp.task('vendor', function() {
   return browserify()
    .require(dependencies)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('vendor.bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(__dirname + '/public/scripts'));
});
```