# How to build my own JS modules in a separate bundle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify

I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330103/how-to-include-node-modules-in-a-separate-browserify-vendor-bundle) example, and many other similar, to separate vendor bundle from main JS file. I've got a multi-entrypoint app. So I'm going to have N HTML files like following

[articles.html]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="articles.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

[categories.html]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="categories.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

and so on.
I have got my own modules, as well. I would like my own modules' code not to be repeated into articles.js, categories.js, etc. But to be bundled or with vendor bundle or in a separate bundle. For example

[articles.html]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mySharedModules.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="articles.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

So, following what it appears to be [the commonly accepted method to build vendor bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330103/how-to-include-node-modules-in-a-separate-browserify-vendor-bundle), I patched the gulpfile into something like

```
const mymod = ['./src/js/mod1.js', './src/js/mod2.js'];

gulp.task('build:mymod', function() {
    const b = browserify();

    mymod .forEach(function(lib) {
        b.require(lib);
    });

    b.bundle()
        .pipe(source('mySharedModules.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

It's been built without errors, but the source path I had to specify (I don't know other way to refer to a module of my own, since it's not a NPM module...) is built hard-coded:

```
...
},{"../mod1.js":"/src/js/mod1.js","jquery":"jquery"}],2:
[function(require,module,exports){
var l = require("../mod1.js");
...
```

Of course the path "/src/js/mod1.js" doesn't make sense in "dist" directory. In fact I get an error: Cannot find module "/src/js/mod1.js".

Which is the correct way to bundle my own shared JS modules, either bundled with vendor's modules or separately?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may lie in the usage of `b.require`. Try passing an `expose` option with your required files.

https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#brequirefile-opts

```
const mymod = [
  {file: './src/js/mod1.js', expose: 'mod1'},
  {file: './src/js/mod2.js', expose: 'mod2'}
];

gulp.task('build:mymod', function() {
    const b = browserify();

    b.require(mymod); // pass array of files w/ 'expose' property

    b.bundle()
        .pipe(source('mySharedModules.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

According to the docs, `require('mod1')` and `require('mod2')` should now be enabled outside of the `mySharedModules.js` bundle.